# UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter Ignore AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to configure Spring Security to accept JSON login payload. However, a side effect of using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` as a custom filter has cause Spring Security to not follow `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` as expected instead, spring redirect request to root page (default spring security config).

Note: If I remove, `addFilterAt` from the configuration and use `FORM URL ENCODED` to login, it will follow to `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` as expected

WebSecurityConfigurer

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(permitURI).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterAt(new JSONAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .successHandler(authSuccess).failureHandler(authFailure).permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntry)
        .and()
        .rememberMe().rememberMeCookieName("AUTOLOGIN")
        .and()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "AUTOLOGIN")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
        .permitAll();

http.csrf().disable();
```

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String payload;
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            payload = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
            JsonAuthenticationParser auth = mapper.readValue(payload, JsonAuthenticationParser.class);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getUsername(), auth.getPassword());

            return authRequest;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    static class JsonAuthenticationParser {
        private final String username;
        private final String password;

        @JsonCreator
        public JsonAuthenticationParser(@JsonProperty("username") String username, @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `setAuthenticationSuccessHandler` method to custom your authentication success action. `setAuthenticationSuccessHandler()` is defined in abstract class `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

Comment: extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` requires implementing tons of methods, is there a simpler way to do this? maybe linking to existing  `successHandler` (`SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`) etc?

Comment: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter already extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. If you already use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, you can just call setAuthenticationSuccessHandler to custom successHandler.Of course,you can use SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler if is needed.

Comment: @XPLOT1ON extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` requires you to implement exactly that one single method you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Your `JsonAuthenticationFilter` looks fine to me (I assume it extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`).

Try the following `WebConfig`:

You should add your `LoginSuccessHandler` directly to the `JsonAuthenticationFilter`.

```
@Bean
public JsonAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    JsonAuthenticationFilter filter = new JsonAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new MyLoginSuccessHandler());
    return filter;
}
```

Add your `JsonauthenticationFilter` before the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did as you said, but getting `IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified`. I changed your `BasicAuthenticationFilter.class` to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class` by the way.

Comment: wait, it does not throw the above exception anymore. However, It does not authenticate the user with `AuthenticationProvider`. It went straight to `successHandler`